# 5 malicious files found in Magento with a malware scan - are they for real or false positive?

Tags: security

```
Magento 1.9.x
Softaculous installer in Cpanel
```

A malware scan on our server has detected the following 5 malicious files - are these really problematic or could these just be false positives?

```
/home/mainaccountuser/ourdomain.com-old/softaculous_backups/errors/default/default.php
/home/mainaccountuser/ourdomain.com/errors/default/default.php
/home/mainaccountuser/ourdomain.com-old/softaculous_backups/errors/default/dev.php
/home/mainaccountuser/ourdomain.com/errors/default/dev.php
/home/mainaccountuser/ourdomain.com-old/softaculous_backups/media/catalog/product/watermark/default/test.gif
```

Our hosting company says: "Please review the report in question on your end with the assistance of a security expert and update us here once the malicious files have been removed or cleaned so that we can run another scan of your account and confirm if any malicious files remain." so they clearly think these are genuine malware threads.

3 of these are in the '**softaculous_backups**' directory. We don't currently use backups from/through Softaculous - we just used the service being part of the Cpanel for the initial install. I should be able to just delete the 'softaculous_backups' directory, right?

What is the errors folder for? Is that part of Magento's functionality? I checked 2 other Magento installs and I don't see either default.php or dev.php so I assume these could be problematic? Is it enough just to delete these files individually? Any other thoughts on this?